# Transferring books between Kindles

Tags: kindle, ebook-management

If I buy a newer and more complete Kindle reader than the one I'm using at present, how can I move my books from one reader to the other?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should be easy if you register the Kindles with the same Amazon account.

1. Connect your Kindles to the same Amazon account.
2. On the new Kindle find from the "home screen" or "main menu" find "cloud" or "archived items" and select it.
3. Select the book you want to download, it should transfer to your Kindle.

You can also do this through the Amazon website.

1. From the Amazon website login to your account.
2. Under the "Your Account" menu click the "Manage Your Kindle" link. A list of your Kindle books appears.
3. Click the "Actions" button beside a the book you want to download. Click "Deliver to my…"
4. Click the "Deliver To" menu. A list of your Kindle devices appears. Select one and then click the "Deliver" button.

Answer (score 6):

When you connect the new device to your account, you will be able to see all of the existing books in your library. You can then download whichever ones you want to have on the new device.